# Mill: How can I build cross build for RootModule?

Tags: scala, build-tools, mill

I have Mill project and currently built for Scala 3.

I'm preparing for cross build for Scala 2.13.

Currently I have this `build.sc`:

```scala
import mill._, scalalib._
import publish._

// qw is my project name
object qw extends Cross[QwModule]("2.13.11", "3.3.0") {
  def defaultCrossSegments = Seq("3.3.0")
}
trait QwModule
    extends Cross.Module[String]
    with RootModule
    with ScalaModule
    with PublishModule
    with Cross.Module[String] {
  def scalaVersion = crossValue
  // ...
}
```

However this doesn't compile:

```bash
% mill 'qw[3.3.0].compile'                                                                                    [39/1074]
[build.sc] [43/52] compile                                                                                             
[info] compiling 1 Scala source to /home/windymelt/src/github.com/windymelt/qw.scala/out/mill-build/compile.dest/classe
s ...                                                                                                                  
[info] done compiling                                                                                                  
[build.sc] [52/52] methodCodeHashSignatures              
Exception in thread "MillServerActionRunner" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out of bounds for length
 0                                                                                                                     
        at scala.collection.immutable.ArraySeq$ofRef.apply(ArraySeq.scala:331)
        at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOps.head(IndexedSeq.scala:94)
        at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOps.head$(IndexedSeq.scala:94)
        at scala.collection.immutable.ArraySeq.head(ArraySeq.scala:35)
        at mill.resolve.Resolve$.mill$resolve$Resolve$$instantiateTarget(Resolve.scala:92)                            
        at mill.resolve.Resolve$Tasks$.$anonfun$handleResolved$3(Resolve.scala:46)
        at scala.util.Either.flatMap(Either.scala:352)
        at mill.resolve.Resolve$Tasks$.$anonfun$handleResolved$2(Resolve.scala:46)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.map(List.scala:246)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.map(List.scala:79)
        at mill.resolve.Resolve$Tasks$.handleResolved(Resolve.scala:42)
        at mill.resolve.Resolve.$anonfun$resolveNonEmptyAndHandle$3(Resolve.scala:241)
        at scala.util.Either.flatMap(Either.scala:352)
        at mill.resolve.Resolve.resolveNonEmptyAndHandle(Resolve.scala:241)
        at mill.resolve.Resolve.resolveNonEmptyAndHandle$(Resolve.scala:223)
        at mill.resolve.Resolve$Tasks$.resolveNonEmptyAndHandle(Resolve.scala:34)
        at mill.resolve.Resolve.$anonfun$resolve0$4(Resolve.scala:207)
        at scala.util.Either.map(Either.scala:382)
        at mill.resolve.Resolve.$anonfun$resolve0$3(Resolve.scala:206)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.map(List.scala:246)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.map(List.scala:79)
        at mill.resolve.Resolve.$anonfun$resolve0$2(Resolve.scala:205)
...
```

How can I build RootModule with cross scala versioning?

Comment: `Mill Build Tool version 0.11.2`

Comment: I wonder how you managed to get this error. Instead, you should see at least one compile error, as your posted `build.sc` doesn't compile and `RootModule` is a class, so it can't be mixed-in with the `with` keyword.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `RootModule` always needs to be a singleton top-level module.

The quick fix to your specific problem is to remove the `extends RootModule` from your `QwModule` trait, and your Mill command should work as expected.

**Some more explanation**

Without an explicit `RootModule`, Mill uses a built-in root module, and all modules you define in your `build.sc` become sub modules of it. Hence, you need to specify their full segmented names or use some patterns when running them from the Mill CLI.

So, to compile a top-level Scala module `qw`, your Mill command is `mill qw.compile`.
Whereas if you make the `qw` module a `RootModule`, your Mill command to compile it is `mill compile`.

Adding a `RootModule` to a `Cross.Module` module violates both requirements:

1. It is no longer a top-level module, as `Cross.Module` instances are sub-modules of their holding `Cross` module.
2. It is not a singleton anymore, as you have many of them (in your case: two), one for each `crossValue`.

**And some other musing**

I wonder how you managed to get this error (`java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`). Instead, you should see at least one compile error, as your posted `build.sc` doesn't compile and `RootModule` is an abstract class, so it can't be mixed-in with the `with` keyword.